# Angular Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, wordpress

I am troubling with  angular js error 
angular.js:36 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.19%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A139)

index.php code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.17/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/style.css" />
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/angular-animate.js"></script >
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/script.js"></script>
  </head>

   <body ng-controller="Ctrll">
        <p style="color:#000;margin:0"><span>slide:</span>{{slide}} </p>


        <button ng-click="showAlerts()" style="float:left"> 
          click to toggle panel
        </button>
        <!--sliding panel directive-->
        <alerts-center ng-if="parentslide"></alerts-center> 


    </body>

</html>
```

js code is

```
angular.module("app",["ngAnimate"])
.controller("Ctrll",function($scope, $timeout){
   $scope.parentslide =false;
 $scope.showAlerts  = function($event) {
         $scope.parentslide =true;
          $timeout(function(){        
             $scope.$broadcast('openAlerts');
          },1)
        }
    })
    .controller('alertsCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.$on('openAlerts', function(event, args) {
            $scope.slide = !$scope.slide;
        });
    })
    .directive('alertsCenter', function () {
        return {
          templateUrl: 'alerts.php',
          replace:true,
          restrict: 'E',
          controller:'alertsCtrl'
        };
    });
```

Comment: Did you link your `js` and `html` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you working in plunker its fine. If not then the error may be due to

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.2.20" data-semver="1.2.19" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular-animate@1.2.17" data-semver="1.2.17" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.17/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

data-require and data-semver are actually specific implementations by Plunker.

Better to use:
**bower install angular-animate**
and add the script tag

```
< script src="/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script >
```

finally Dependency injection

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```

Comment: [<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.17/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/style.css" />
 <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/angular-animate.js"></script >
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/script.js"></script>
  </head>]

Comment: please look the edited code , this all code is working with simple html, but when i convert this in wordpress  then  code is not working

Comment: Make sure you properly converting the code in wordpress. I will try to check with the issue but I am new to wordpress.

Comment: hey it's working , uncaught error is resolved thanks for your support

Comment: No problem. share the solution so that it may be useful for others.